# Define material from Ogden–Holzapfel two-fiber strain-energy function in Ansys

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, simulation, ansys, ansys-workbench

I'm trying to do a FSI simulation with properties, described in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/10255842.2018.1439478) and for the structural properties, the authors use an Ogden–Holzapfel two-fiber strain-energy function to describe the solid material as you can see in the picture below.
To define this material in Ansys Transient Structural's Engineering Data, First, I tried to use the Odgen 3rd order from Hyperelastic section but the constants and variables needed to define it are different from what we have in the paper.
Is there anyways to use Odgen 3rd order or should I write a function myself? I did some research and I couldn't understand how should I write a function to define a material.
[image]